# My stylesheets are not enqueuing

Tags: plugin-development, css, wp-enqueue-script

I'm in Wordpress 4.5.2 on Windows 10 and I'm trying to register and enqueue my stylesheet in Wordpress, but it just isn't working. I'm having the same problem with jQuery.

I have this code in a plugin, and I am displaying a dashboard widget, which is working just fine:

```
<?php
    /*
     *   Plugin Name: TEST PLUGIN
    */

    /*  register styles and scripts
    *   register dash widgets
    *
    */

    function register_styles() {

        wp_register_script( 'wildstyle', plugins_url('css/wildstyle.css', __FILE__ ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'wildstyle' );
    }

    function register_dash_widget() {

        wp_add_dashboard_widget(
             'test-widget',
             'Test Widget',
             'display_callback'
        );
    }

    /*  add all the actions
    *   
    *
    */

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_styles' );
    add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_dash_widget' );

    /*  display callback for dashboard metabox
    *
    *
    */

    function display_callback() {

        echo '<p>Testing, testing...</p>';
    }
```

Here is the little bit of css that I'm using for the test:

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

Why is my text not red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add stylesheet in back-office, but you need for that use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

See Codex reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Awesome. That worked, thanks. I also needed to use wp_register_style/wp_register_script in register_styles().

Comment: In this hook you can also add style or script. This is your quest ?

Comment: It wasn't a question, I was just adding some extra info for anyone else who might come across this question. Just using admin_enqueue_scripts didn't work, at first, but when I changed `wp_enqueue_script` to `wp_enqueue_style` (and the same with register), it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change both lines:

```
wp_register_script( 'wildstyle', plugins_url('css/wildstyle.css', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wildstyle' );
```

to

```
wp_register_style( 'wildstyle', plugins_url('css/wildstyle.css', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'wildstyle' );
```